# correct use of the MVC and Singleton Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I have a couple of apps which have been approved by Apple but i'm trying to understand the MVC pattern and in particular the Singleton class. I'm now modifying my code to follow this pattern. I have tried the Singleton class but i'm missing something. Values in the sharedInstance are available in my Model Class but I cant find the answer to this simple question;

I have a class called 'Data', do I create the singleton class and make it a subclass of 'Data' or do I make the 'Data' class a Singleton and private all my functions? My main problem is understanding how to pass data between classes without using a Segue.

Comment: Can you please be more clear about the problem statement.

Comment: Singletons are considered bad anyway. Better to pass a reference to your data model via the segue.

Comment: I cannot use a Segue as the .swift file does not have a UI! I generally understand why I would use a Singleton but I want to use this as part of the MVC pattern. Can  I create a .swift file with a class and create a sharedInstance of that class? to allow my Model data global access by the View and Controllers while making all my Functions within that class Private to prevent more than one instance?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, segues are for passing data between view controllers and not simple objects.

And regarding your question about singletons, here's how I do it:

```
class MyClass {

    // Swift's let is lazy-initialized and is thread safe.
    static let sharedSingleton = MyClass()

    private init() {}

    private func printSomething(){
        println("Something")
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
MyClass.sharedSingleton.printSomething()
```

Comment: No, I was using Segues to pass data between ViewControllers but I didn't have a MVC pattern. For each ViewController I had the data for that View. So my understanding is; I create a .swift file with a class and create a sharedInstance of that class? to allow my Model data global access by the View and Controllers while making all my Functions within that class Private to prevent more than one instance?

Comment: I frankly don't get what exactly do you intent to do.
Anyway, you can watch lecture 7 (Multiple MVCs) offered by stanford, really valuable: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/
Lectures are available for free through iTunesU. Hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks anyway for replying. I think I know the right way and I already listened to the Stanford videos.

Comment: Swift is different from Objective C in that it wants you to use structs, enums and types as much as possible. Structs are passed by value (copied), thus you don't have the problem of risking your model objects are getting changed from different places. Objects are passed by reference and thus much more unsafe. You can use delegates to pass values between classes, which is great especially with asynchronous calls to backend databases, etc.